# does mousedown /mouseup in jquery work for the ipad?

Tags: jquery, ipad, onmousedown

I am using the current code:

```
$('body').mousedown(function() {
        $('div#extras').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});

$('body').mouseup(function() {
        $('div#extras').delay(2000).fadeTo(1500, 0);
});
```

This works great in safari but when I upload it and check it out on the ipad it doesnt work?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I found out how to do this for the ipad for those who are interested:

Instead of the code I used in my question, you would use:

```
$('body').bind( "touchstart", function(e){
        $('div#extras').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

&

```
$('body').bind( "touchend", function(e){
        $('div#extras').delay(2000).fadeTo(1500, 0);
});
```

Comment: $('body').on( "mousedown touchstart", function(e){
    // this would work on desktop and mobile devices at the same time
})

Comment: Just want to add, don't forget to use `e.preventDefault()` in case of overlay/model-popup.

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1)

Quote:

> A clickable element is a link, form element, image map area, or any other element with
>   mousemove, **mousedown**, **mouseup**, or onclick handlers. A scrollable element is any
>   element with appropriate overflow style, text areas, and scrollable iframe  elements.
>   Because of these differences, you might need to change some of your elements to
>   clickable elements, as described in “[Making Elements Clickable](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6),” to get the desired
>   behavior in iPhone OS.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that, but its working perfectly for me on the ipad. :)

Answer (score 6):

Not really answering your question, but may be handy for people who came here just to look for 'jQuery mousedown/mouseup on ipad'

I always use this little trick:

```
$(element).hover(function() {
   // Do something
});
```

This triggers on touch when using an iPad *and reverses the action when clicking outside of the element* since it's an hover event. So for example:

```
// Assuming the element has 'opacity: 0' in CSS

$(element).hover(function() {
   $(this).animate({'opacity': 1}, 200);
});
```

Creates a fade in effect 'on click', and a fade out effect 'on mouseup'.

Answer (score 6):

Old post but there is universal solution:

```
$('body').on('mousedown touchstart',function(e){
    $('div#extras').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('body').on('mouseup touchend',function(e){
    $('div#extras').delay(2000).fadeTo(1500, 0);
});
```

You will notice that I use `mousedown` with `touchstart` and `mouseup` with `touchend`. This cover mobile and desktop use.