# Check to see if a HTML button is released

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I want to be able to tell when a html button is no longer clicked/touched so I can change a boolean from true to false.

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Click to start." onclick="playIt();" />
```

I way to see if it's currently still pressed would work as well.

Comment: Check `mouseup` or `keyup` events and bind the events that you need.

Comment: @Sachin Does mouseup still work when a button is released on mobile?

Comment: I have not used it but seems like there is `touchstart` and `touchend` events that you can bind your functions to. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3303834/2860358

Comment: Okay if mouseUp doesn't work I'll just have to do all four

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `onmouseup` to your button:

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Click to start." onmouseup="playIt();">
```

Comment: Thanks, worked easy enough and if it doesn't work on some mobile devices I'll just have to do the same for touchstart and touchend.

Comment: I think this will do on any browser, cause it's been part of HTML specification for a long time. Thank you for your return.